# Javascript menu bold selected, un-bold the rest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have an ASP MVC app that has a menu with some JavaScript behind to move from page to page. As it is now, when I select a menu item, it becomes bold. But it stays bold even when I select a different menu item. So if I click all the menu items, they all become bold and stay that way.

Here is the code for one menu item:

```
<script>
    $('#firstMenuItem').click(function () {
        $('#div').load(
            "@Url.Action("FirstMenu","SomeItem")",
            { 'id':'123'}, 
            function (response, status, xhr) {
                if (status == "error") {
                    alert("An error occurred while loading the data.");
                }
            });
        this.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    });
</script>
```

I want to change this code so that when I select another menu item, only that one will become bold, and the rest will be normal font.
How could I do this?

Comment: 1) traverse all menu options, render as normal before setting the last selection to bold. 2) Remember the last selection. When a new selection is made, render the old one to normal, and then set the new selection to bold.

Comment: please provide html coding

Comment: <table style="color:#BCBEC2;">
    <tr>
        <td id="FirstMenu" style="border-bottom:1px solid;" >
            FirstMenu
        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td id="SecondMenu" style="border-bottom:1px solid;">
            SecondMenu
        </td>
    </tr>

Comment: the menu is placed inside a table. on each row, there is a td with the name of the menu item inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery provides a [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function you can use, assuming the menu items live in the same parent element.

```
$(this).siblings().css('font-weight', 'normal')
```

Here's a quick demo: https://jsfiddle.net/terbt1Lt/

Comment: I can't acces the .siblings(). I am using jquery.touchSwipe.min.js and jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js. Other than that, your quick demo is what I want in my app.

Comment: might be because i have the menu items inside table tr td.

Comment: In that case, check out the rest of jQuery's [traversing functions](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/), specifically `closest()`, `parent()` and `children()`. Or, if all of your items have an `#id`, you can turn everything `normal` then turn the new selection `bold`. That will require changes to your JS if you add new menu items in the future.